# How can I align two bootstrap col divs with a 3rd col div off to the left?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the result as you can see here:
[image]

The code I am tried to get it to work is this code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Welkom Dennis,</h1>
    <div class="col-12 card card-body mb-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center d-flex">
                    <img class="mx-auto my-auto" src="img/foot.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 card card-body mb-2">
                <p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 card card-body mb-2">
                <p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It results as shown here:
[image]

So what I am trying to get is that there are 2 columns under each other next to the foot.
I tried several things but I can't get it the way I would like it too.

Comment: You should really read the Bootstrap documentation to see how you are supposed use the grid system.

Comment: @Roope Because I am doing something wrong? or do I need to read it so I get to know how to do it? because if I am doing it wrong tell me please

Comment: Please [READ the Bootstrap grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#how-it-works) ... the code you've posted is not the correct structure. `col` is always the immediate children of `row`

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the col-3, col-3, and col-8 all under one row that only spans col-12. So the third col-8 has no where to go but to wrap under its siblings.

Think of it as two columns col-4, col-8 (which === 12) and inside the col-8 stack the cards for the text and buttons.

Example:

```
<div class="container">

<h1>Welkom Dennis,</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 card card-body mb-2">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Foot Image Column -->
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <img class="mx-auto img-fluid" src="img/foot.png">
            </div>

            <!-- Text and Buttons Column -->
            <div class="col-md-8">

                <!-- Inside this column you have stacked cards -->

                <div class="card card-body mb-2">
                    <p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="card card-body">
                    <p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!